# Facebook API v3 - publish_to_groups Not Working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to update my app to use the new group permissions, specifically publish_to_groups. The oauth process works fine but when I go to post I'm getting...

"(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission"

I'm testing through Graph Explorer so it's not anything specific to my code. The error mentions publish_actions but that has been deprecated for v3 and isn't available to add when I get my token. Looking at the publishing docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/feed#publish that is still showing publish_actions as well.

Has anyone come across this yet?

Comment: There is a known issue with publish_to_groups... https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/591496304558468/

Answer (score 3):

As of April 2018, the Group Edge has been deprecated. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/

Comment: They have now actually enabled Group edge again, and added new permissions:  
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/group